# How to print number is duplicate but not contiguous in array

Tags: python, arraylist

How to print number is duplicate but not contiguous in array?

example input : `[5,2,2,3,3,5]`

output : `5`

I don't know what to do, I've tried but I can't check the list.

Comment: Please update your question with the `"many ways"` you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to keep track of the seen values:

```
l = [5,2,2,3,3,5]

from itertools import groupby

seen = set()
duplicates = set()
for k, _ in groupby(l):
    if k in seen:
        print(f'{k} is duplicated')
        duplicates.add(k)
    seen.add(k)
```

Output:

```
5 is duplicated
```

content of `duplicates`:

```
{5}
```